# Delphi Indy IRC

Tags: delphi, indy, irc

Delphi version : XE2,
Indy version: 10.5.8.0.
I have three procedures and all work fine until internet connection gets lost. When it will happen  and after that I will try sending message then I can't reconnect when internet will be back. Can't close program (after on close program be not visible, but will use 100 cpu usage). Without "try, exception" there is a `Socket Error #1053` on IdIRC1.Say and on Close. Thanks for help.

```
///Connection:

    procedure TForm1.Button5Click(Sender : TObject);
    begin
      try
        IdIRC1.Nickname := 'zzz';
        IdIRC1.Password := 'kkk';
        if IdIRC1.Connected then
          IdIRC1.Disconnect;
        IdIRC1.Connect;
        IdIRC1.Join('#' + edit3.Text);
      except
        ShowMessage('ggg');
      end;
    end;

///Send message:

procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender : TObject);
begin
 try
    IdIRC1.Say('#' + edit3.Text, edit2.Text);
    if (edit2.Text <> '') and (IdIRC1.Connected) then
    begin
      memo6.Lines.Add(edit2.Text);
      Edit2.Clear;
    end
    else
      ShowMessage('xxx');
 except
    ShowMessage('yyy');
 end;
end;



///On close:
  try
    IdIRC1.Disconnect;
  except
  end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you encounter an error accessing the connection, such as because the connection was lost, you need to call `Disconnect()` **and** you need to clear the `IOHandler.InputBuffer` if it still has unread data in it.  `Disconnect()` does not clear the `InputBuffer`, by design.  If the `InputBuffer` is not empty, `Connected()` will return True even if the physical socket is disconnected.

Comment: idirc1.Disconnect();
IdIRC1.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Clear;   still i have Socket Error #1053 after use IdIRC1.Say while internet connection was lost.

Comment: before IdIRC1.Say i added function which check if Internet is available.God bless no more Socket Error #1053 error -.-

Comment: When the connection has been lost, you need to disconnect and then reconnect before you can then send new data again. Sounds like maybe you were ignoring the reconnect part.

Comment: Yes. Right now it dont allow to send a message if connection has been lost otherwise program will be dead.

Comment: @user2512579: Sure, if you know ahead of time that the connection is dead. But don't forget to still handle exceptions for cases when you don't know yet that the connection is dead, since the connection might die in between socket operations.